# How to integrate an array between two limits

Tags: python

Basically I have a 10000 long array, which I'd like to integrate between  0 and 63 for example. The issue is that i can't use cumtrapz or other functions because what I want is the definite integral to compute the mean value, and all those functions give arrrays.

In my case A(t) is not a function, what I have is a set of numbers [0.089 ... 0.096], and i'd like to compute the mean by integration

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please clearify your issue :)

Comment: let me know if its clear now